# Where can I find detailed information on available Topology manager scripts

Tags: web8, powershell, topology-manager, sdl-tridion

Need information on all available Powershell Scripts to manage the Topology Manager environment

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found 2 very useful links one from [the documentation](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-3BD6ED93-41B7-4357-92DB-8AEA8DEFB0A1) and the other from [Dominic's blog](http://www.dominic.cronin.nl/weblog/finding-your-way-around-the-sdl-web-8-cmdlets). Both of these provide details on all available cmdlets (commandlets). Dominic's blog goes a step further and explains how to get this information from available Modules. Also providing the way to look for parameters and help on these modules.

[image]

There are a few more commands of interest:

[Decommissioning a Content Delivery environment](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-74588DED-4606-468C-8374-3A9DD3DEB510) : Clear-TtmCdEnvironment,   Clear-TtmMapping

[Deactivating and reactivating a Content Delivery environment for maintenance](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-C22AE1FF-B653-4629-9AB4-8FF6718CC4DC): Disable-TtmCdEnvironment,    Enable-TtmCdEnvironment,    Sync-TtmCdEnvironment

[Exporting and importing Content Delivery information between Topology Manager Instances](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-C22AE1FF-B653-4629-9AB4-8FF6718CC4DC#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Web-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3DSync%255C-TtmCdEnvironment&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1464330335662&currentQuery=Sync%255C-TtmCdEnvironment&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-0AE56164-F4FC-45E6-81D7-95D82A701E8D&query=Sync%255C-TtmCdEnvironment&scope=&filename=GUID-0AE56164-F4FC-45E6-81D7-95D82A701E8D.xml&docid=GUID-0AE56164-F4FC-45E6-81D7-95D82A701E8D&inner_id=&tid=cddcc393-54ee-44cc-a869-d5b31b7c92c7&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false): Export-TtmCdStructure,    Import-TtmCdStructure

[Setting up Site Types for the Site Wizard](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-87A938C3-249A-42DD-AD6D-45CC4BDA41DD): Add-TtmSiteTypeKey, Remove-TtmSiteTypeKey

Comment: Nice overview! It's lacking a column for adding, though (cmdlets named `Add-TtmXYZ`). Furthermore, these are names of PowerShell cmdlets (commandlets), not scripts.

Comment: @RickPannekoek added the "add" column and information on more commands available. Thanks for the suggestion